# Getting back hidden language templates in "New Project..." dialog?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When I first started Visual Studio 2010 I selected the Business Intelligence Environment but now I also want to see the Visual Basic environment. How can I get back access to the VB.net template for new projects?

When I click on New project It shows me Business Intelligence, SQL Server, and Other Project Types, which only has 'blank Solution' in it. I am hoping to being able to create bew BI projects and new VB.net projects.

Thank You!

Comment: If you go to "Tools"->"Import and Export Settings..." you should be able to find a way through the dialogs to do that. You might want to save your current settings first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset your settings in Visual Studio 2010:

1. On the **Tools** menu, click **Import and Export Settings**.
2. On the **Welcome to the Import and Export Settings Wizard** page, click **Reset all settings** and then click **Next**.
3. If you want to save your current settings combination, click **Yes, save my current settings**, specify a file name, and then click **Next**.

—or—

If you want to delete your current settings combination, choose **No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings**, and then click **Next**. This option does not delete default settings, which will still be available the next time you use the wizard.

4. In **Which collection of settings do you want to reset to**, select a settings collection from the list.
5. Click **Finish**.

The **Reset Complete** page alerts you to any problems encountered during the reset.

Reference:

- [How to: Reset Your Settings @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms247075(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Hm, thank you for your answer. I did this and it went through without error, however, when I now click on New Project, it still doesn't give me anything else than BI & SQL. I am looking for a selection of VB projects, such as vb.net console solution, vb.net windows forms solution etc...

Comment: @MarcoK: Can you add a screenshot to your question? It should be there, even without resetting anything. Maybe you installed BI studio without the regular Visual Studio? Looks like it.

Comment: Looks like they put on a new installation and didn't install the actual languages. That's why your solution did not work, otherwise it would have. Thank You!